# android App not getting the message from C2DM server

Tags: android, android-c2dm

we implemented a app to use the C2DM services, we are able to get the registration Id from C2DM server for the app. we are also having the app server which having the AUTH key from C2DM. we are sending the Message from app server and getting the Id response from C2DM, but our application does not receive any message.

We tried it on Android emulator and On Android device (HTC) with wifi connection.